# Aero Theme Checkbox Performance

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, aero

I have a set of data that I display in a TreeView.  The TreeView is styled so that it will contain a checkbox next to each item in the tree.  The behavior of the checkbox is that checking a parent will check all of its children, and unchecking the parent will uncheck all of its children.

The issue arises when the number of children items becomes large (1000+).  Checking a parent will result in a several second delay while all of the children also become checked. and vice versa with unchecking the parent.

I've narrowed down the issue to the Aero theme and it's animation of the checkbox when the IsChecked state changes.  If I change my application to a non-Aero theme, then there is no noticeable delay.

Is anyone aware of any options available to be able to disable the Aero checkbox animation, or am I most likely stuck with needing to roll a custom TreeView control so I can apply a non-aero theme to the checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to create my own checkbox template so remove the animation of the Aero theme.  Once this was done, the checking/unchecking was near instantaneous for large collections.